# Ruby link_to options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, link-to

I need to add an id element into a session array in my rails application. I have the id when I bring up this view, product.id, and i have my session, called session[:cart], waiting for input.

I want to push that id into the session when I click on the link below.

`<%= link_to "Add to Cart", controller: "my_cart" %>`

Is there more to this link I add? i have been looking all over the internet and have not come up with exactly what I'm looking for.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your **product.id** to some **controller/action** where that **controller/action** will add the **product id** to the **session**. It cant be done on the browser side as Sessions are **server driven**

`<%= link_to "Add to Cart", add_product_to_cart_path(:product_id => product.id) %>`

and method would be something like

`def add_product_to_cart`

`session[:cart] << params[:product_id]`

`end`

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is make a action in controller where you can put product.id in your session[:cart] and put the path of that action into link_to for example:-

```
<%= link_to "Add to Cart",your_action_path %>
```

and to see the path of your action you can run rake routes in terminal, just put that path in there and it should do it